# How to split NSArray into UITableView sections alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have having trouble using an indexed table with section headers. Currently I have the indexes down the right hand side and I have the section headers showing correctly, the headers only show if there is data inside of that section.

The problem I am having is splitting the NSArray into parts so I can calculate the numberOfRowsInSections correctly. Currently I have the correct number of sections displaying with the correct headers but all of the data is in each section, rather than being split depending on the first letter of the name.

Here is a screenshot of how it currently looks:[image: All of the data goes into each sections, 5 rows in each. The number of sections (3) is correct]

All of the data goes into each sections, 5 rows in each. The number of sections (3) is correct

My code for this is as follows:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [firstLetterArray objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    NSMutableSet *mySet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    BRConnection *connection = nil;
    NSMutableArray *firstNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (connection in _connections)
    {
        [firstNames addObject:connection.firstName];
    }
    firstNamesArray = firstNames;
    NSLog(@"%@", firstNamesArray);
    for ( NSString *s in firstNames)
    {
        if ([s length] > 0)
            [mySet addObject:[s substringToIndex:1]];
    }

    NSArray *indexArray = [[mySet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    firstLetterArray = indexArray;

    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"{search}"])
    {
        [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, -tableView.contentInset.top)];
        return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
    }
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ConnectionCell"];

    // Display connection in the table cell
    BRConnection *connection = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        connection = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        connection = [_connections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = connection.fullName;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TitilliumText25L-400wt" size:18];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = connection.company;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TitilliumText25L-400wt" size:12];

    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSUInteger sections = [firstLetterArray count];
    return sections;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [_connections count];
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I just cant seem to split the NSArray conenctions into a alphabetical list to get the correct rows in a section. Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: I'd be tempted to make my backing structure a dictionary of arrays.  Given a key, which would be the name of a section, you could retrieve the array of connections that matched and return its count.

Comment: @PhillipMills - an array of arrays is a better choice, since sections are ordered and dictionaries are not.

Comment: @danh I'm torn between the two methods. This case is basically textbook for dictionary use. It's essentially a dictionary after all! But it would make the table population a little more complicated. Using an array, on the other hand, would make the sorting a little more complicated.

Comment: One of my questions can help you sort the data source/NSArray into proper A-Z format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964377/sort-nsarray-of-nsdictionaries-using-comparator The answerer's answer is amazing!

Comment: @troop231 I think it could be done more simply than that... I'll try to write out an answer...

Comment: @danh Actually, since he already has a firstLetterArray array, perhaps a dictionary isn't a bad idea since there's already a recorded order.  I used an array of arrays though in my answer since it would work even without the firstLetterArray... I might return to this later today...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where and how are you populating `_connections`? You're using that array to decide the number of rows per section and to populate those rows, but `_connections`is returning the entire list. You need to split the data in `_connections` up alphabetically.

For example, perhaps you could use an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArray`s to group the data by letter. Since you already seem to know how to sort alphabetically, now you just need to identify the first characters of each string to group them properly. To do this, try:

```
NSString *currentPrefix;

// Store sortedConnections as a class variable (as you've done with _connections)
// so you can access it to populate your table
sortedConnections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Go through each connection (already ordered alphabetically)
for (BRConnection *connection in _connections) {

    // Find the first letter of the current connection
    NSString *firstLetter = [connection.fullName substringToIndex:1];

    // If the last connection's prefix (stored in currentPrefix) is equal
    // to the current first letter, just add the connection to the final
    // array already in sortedConnections
    if ([currentPrefix isEqualToString:firstLetter]) {
        [[sortedConnected lastObject] addObject:connection];
    }

    // Else create a new array in sortedConnections to contain connections starting
    // with this current connection's letter.
    else {
        NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObject:connection];
        [sortedConnections addObject:newArray];
    }

    // To mark this latest array's prefix, set currentPrefix to contain firstLetter
    currentPrefix = firstLetter;
}
```

(This sort would work even if the first letters are unknown.)

Then to get the number of rows per section, use `[sortedConnections objectAtIndex:section]` instead of _connections:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [[sortedSearchResults objectAtIndex:section] count]; // hypothetically
    } else {
        return [[sortedConnections objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
}
```

And to populate the table essentially do the same using `[sortedConnections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ConnectionCell"];

    // Display connection in the table cell
    BRConnection *connection = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        connection = [[sortedSearchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // hypothetically
    } else {
        connection = [[sortedConnections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = connection.fullName;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TitilliumText25L-400wt" size:18];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = connection.company;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TitilliumText25L-400wt" size:12];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I put this in my project but I'm having an issue when it comes to setting the textLabel for the cell. I'm being told there is no selector `fullName` for the NSArray sortedConnections but when I debug I can see that there is. I wasn't 100% sure where to put the code in the first section of the answer so I put it after I set the value of `_connections`, in the same method. Any idea why this would be? Thanks

Comment: fullName belongs to the BRConnection object, not the sorted array... I just added the full cellForRowAtIndexPath method (copied and pasted in your original code to the end). Does your code look like the above code where cell.textLabel.text = connection.fullName or did you do something like cell.textLabel.text = [sortedConnections objectAtIndex:section].fullName?

Comment: I tried using both methods you have specified there, the second `cell.textLabel.text = [sortedConnections objectAtIndex:section].fullName` wouldn't compile. But the compiler also won't let me use `section` in `objectAtIndex`, I changed it to `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` but I'm not sure thats correct as it still doesn't work, still tells me `fullName` is unrecognised. Also this line `        connection = [[sortedConnections objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` wouldn't work as section is undefined. Should the section variable be used or not?

Comment: `cell.textLabel.text = [sortedConnections objectAtIndex:section].fullName` is wrong. Try what I wrote above. And sorry, I did some sloppy copy and pasting. `section` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be `indexPath.section`. Edited.

Comment: And also make sure you've sorted `_connections` before using this sorting method.

Comment: @LyndseyScott +1 for a thoughtful, well commented answer.  A couple suggestions - don't make the indexing dependent on a sorted input, you could even start out with the outer collection as a set, then finalize as an array, sorted by the first letter of the first object in each inner array.  Also, using modern array[index] syntax would shorten the code and add readability.  Finally, the prettier way to get first letter is substringToIndex:1.

Comment: Initially was going to do substringToIndex since it would return an `NSString` but I thought it would be easier to understand what I was doing by using characterAtIndex:0 instead... I think you're right though -- substringToIndex:1 is more elegant. And yeah, I think I'll change the answer so it doesn't take the OP's sorted input for granted, since there's no need to sort twice if you don't have to. That way it would be more useful for future answer-seekers. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @LyndseyScott I cant get my index to scroll to the correct section, when i log the index and title it displays correctly but the table doesn't move. in my sectionForSectionIndexTitle method I return `return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index]`

Comment: @danh I thought it over and I think it would actually be more efficient to do a pre-sort as I've specified because otherwise, if you do it dynamically while inserting the connections into the array, the algorithm would require at minimum a binary sort with each array insertion and a separate binary sort when identifying the proper array.

Comment: @adamtrousdale This new question is unrelated to your original question though... You'll have to ask the new question in a different thread. Is the table now grouped properly though?

Answer (score 5):

Hope that helps you, i don't know if is the best way to do, but it works =)

```
NSArray *names = @[@"Ana Carolina", @"Ana carolina", @"Ana luiza", @"leonardo", @"fernanda", @"Leonardo Cavalcante"];

NSMutableSet *firstCharacters = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:0];
for( NSString*string in names ){
    [firstCharacters addObject:[[string substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
}
NSArray *allLetters = [[firstCharacters allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
int indexLetter = 0;
NSMutableArray *separeNamesByLetters = [NSMutableArray new];



for (NSString *letter in allLetters) {
    NSMutableDictionary*userBegeinsWith = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [userBegeinsWith setObject:letter forKey:@"letter"];
    NSMutableArray *groupNameByLetters = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSString *compareLetter1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", allLetters[indexLetter]];
    for (NSString*friendName in names) {
        NSString *compareLetter2 = [[friendName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];

        if ( [compareLetter1 isEqualToString:compareLetter2] ) {
            [groupNameByLetters addObject:friendName];
        }
    }
    indexLetter++;
    [userBegeinsWith setObject:groupNameByLetters forKey:@"list"];
    [separeNamesByLetters addObject: userBegeinsWith];
}



NSLog(@"%@", separeNamesByLetters);
```

output:

```
 (
        {
        letter = A;
        list =         (
            "ana carolina",
            "Ana carolina",
            "Ana luiza"
        );
    },
        {
        letter = F;
        list =         (
            fernanda
        );
    },
        {
        letter = L;
        list =         (
            leonardo,
            "Leonardo Cavalcante"

        )
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have custom objects , little modification in @Leo

```
NSMutableSet *firstCharacters = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:0];
        for( ETUser *user in self.follwings){
            [firstCharacters addObject:[[user.name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
        }
        NSArray *allLetters = [[firstCharacters allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        int indexLetter = 0;
        NSMutableArray *separeNamesByLetters = [NSMutableArray new];


        for (NSString *letter in allLetters) {

            NSMutableDictionary*userBegeinsWith = [NSMutableDictionary new];

            [userBegeinsWith setObject:letter forKey:@"letter"];

            NSMutableArray *groupNameByLetters = [NSMutableArray new];

            NSString *compareLetter1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", allLetters[indexLetter]];

            for (ETUser *user in self.follwings) {

                NSString *compareLetter2 = [[user.name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];

                if ( [compareLetter1 isEqualToString:compareLetter2] ) {

                    [groupNameByLetters addObject:user];
                }
            }
            indexLetter++;
            [userBegeinsWith setObject:groupNameByLetters forKey:@"list"];
            [separeNamesByLetters addObject: userBegeinsWith];
        }

        self.follwings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:separeNamesByLetters];
```